# How to programmatically set ga_trackingId property?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a single app, but depending of user's choice, it will be monitored totally separated in google analytics, so I NEED to set "ga_trackingId" for EasyTracker programmatically.

I've tried `EasyTracker.getTracker().setAppId(id)` with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For changing the id for the EasyTracker, do this:

**onStart()**

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).set(Fields.TRACKING_ID, "<your_ga_id");
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
```

**onStop()**

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, as I saw this in my logs:

```
`W/GAV3﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Missing tracking id (&tid)`
```

The solution for analytics v3 is:

```
EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getContext());
tracker.set("&tid", "UA-XXXX-2");
```

Calling it this way got rid of the error and I can see my events on the analytics page.

Answer (score 3):

You can have two different config xml files and set it like this:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
```

Note, that you are passing xml file, **not** the trackingId file:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(R.string.ga_trackingId);
```

Note the difference **xml.app_tracker** vs **string.ga_trackingId**!

Use `xml.app_tracker` configuration file!

Comment: you can also use analytics.newTracker(getString(R.string.ga_trackingId))

Answer (score 1):

```
GoogleAnalytics ga = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity());
  tracker = ga.getTracker(getString(R.string.ga_trackingId));
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it myself, but from description in [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced), you can create a new tracker by

```
Context mCtx = this; // Get current context.
GoogleAnalytics myInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
Tracker myNewTracker = myInstance.getTracker("UA-XXXX-2") // A new tracking ID.
```

Comment: Does this actually set the id on EasyTracker?  I don't see EasyTracker in this code at all

Answer (score 0):

i found `myInstance.setDefaultTracker(myNewTracker);` not working. I did this instead:
Set up a common library project. Each apk project gets a analytics.xml in res\values folder with its unique id.

Answer (score -1):

In values folder create xml file which name is analytics.xml

analytics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-37995114-1</string>

    <!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

Add new V2 library file(jar file)

```
link :- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events
```

I Hop its useful to you.

Comment: This is not progremmatically

Comment: okay, but how can I activate this file ? is it automatic ? How can I add more paras, for example the flush time ?