# Google Analytics Android SDK setting analytics ID dynamically and onStart

Tags: android, google-analytics

Inside my activity I was using Google Analytics like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
     Context con = getApplicationContext();
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(con).activityStart(con);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(con).activityStop(con);
}
```

But now I need to change Analytics Ids. But I don't want to change id from analytics.xml. I need to set it from code. From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423273/how-to-programmatically-set-ga-trackingid-property) it seems like there exists `getTracker` method.

```
public class MyUtil {
    private static final gaDebugMode = false;

    public static Tracker getGAtracker(Context pContext) {
        String gaId;
        if (gaDebugMode) {
            gaId = "UA-12345-7";
        } else {
            gaId = "UA-44444-7";
        }
        return GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(pContext).getTracker( gaId );
    }
}
```

But I couldn't find how to call analytics in `onStart()` and `onStop()`. This doesn't help

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    Context con = getApplicationContext();
    super.onStart();
    MyUtil.getGAtracker(con).activityStart(con);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my onStart and onStop for my analytics.

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // The rest of your onStart() code.
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The rest of your onStop() code.
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method.
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer. I need to change analytics ID dynamically.